# If $n$ is odd, show that there are at most 36 group homomorphisms from $D_n$ to $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $n$ is odd, then how to show that there are at most 36 group homomorphisms from $D_n$ to $A_4$?

I simply do not have any idea. Please help.

Comment: How many elements of odd order does $A_4$ contain?

Comment: Actually I don't see how there could be that many for any odd $n$. The Sylow 3-subgroups of $A_4$ are self-normalizing, no?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. If you know where the generators of $D_n$ go (under a homomorphism), you know where everything goes.
2. An element of order $m$ must be mapped to an element of order dividing $m$.

Now if you know a good pair of generators of $D_n$, and if you know the orders of the elements of $A_4$, you should be well on your way.